# How to split the final value in arrays into its own array?

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have an array of arrays each containing 5 values. I want to split the last value from each array in the overall array into its own array but I can't figure out the best way to do it.

```
FeatureVectors = [[4, 0.001743713493735165, 0.6497055601752815, 90.795723552739275, 2], [4, 0.0460937435599832, 0.19764217920409227, 90.204147248752378, 2], [1, 0.001185534503063044, 0.3034913722821194, 60.348908179729023, 2], [1, 0.015455289770298222, 0.8380914254332884, 109.02120657826231, 2], [3, 0.0169961646358455, 41.36919146079211, 136.83829993466398, 2]]
```

In this case the last values in the arrays are all 2 but this isn't always the case.

I want to get this:

```
FeatureVectors = [[4, 0.001743713493735165, 0.6497055601752815, 90.795723552739275], [4, 0.0460937435599832, 0.19764217920409227, 90.204147248752378], [1, 0.001185534503063044, 0.3034913722821194, 60.348908179729023], [1, 0.015455289770298222, 0.8380914254332884, 109.02120657826231], [3, 0.0169961646358455, 41.36919146079211, 136.83829993466398]]

Labels = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us some code you already tried ?

Comment: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); don't use `FeatureVectors` and `Labels` as variable names. Use `feature_vectors` and `labels` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach(with list comprehension):

```
FeatureVectors = [[4, 0.001743713493735165, 0.6497055601752815, 90.795723552739275, 2], [4, 0.0460937435599832, 0.19764217920409227, 90.204147248752378, 2], [1, 0.001185534503063044, 0.3034913722821194, 60.348908179729023, 2], [1, 0.015455289770298222, 0.8380914254332884, 109.02120657826231, 2], [3, 0.0169961646358455, 41.36919146079211, 136.83829993466398, 2]]
FeatureVectors, Labels = ([i[:-1] for i in FeatureVectors], [i[-1] for i in FeatureVectors])

print(FeatureVectors, Labels, sep='\n')
```

The output(consecutively):

```
[[4, 0.001743713493735165, 0.6497055601752815, 90.79572355273928], [4, 0.0460937435599832, 0.19764217920409227, 90.20414724875238], [1, 0.001185534503063044, 0.3034913722821194, 60.34890817972902], [1, 0.015455289770298222, 0.8380914254332884, 109.02120657826231], [3, 0.0169961646358455, 41.36919146079211, 136.83829993466398]]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it done in one shot:

```
Labels = [vector.pop() for vector in FeatureVectors]
```